# Why are "Extracted Interfaces" Internal rather than Public?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, conventions

Visual Studio includes a refactoring function called "Extract Interface" that generates an interface based on a class implementation.

The extracted interfaces are Internal by default.  Problem is, we end up changing nearly all of them to `Public`.

Does anyone know why it's Internal by default?  Better yet, is there a way to customize this to default to `Public`?

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you change the Visual Studio template for interfaces (I haven't tried that but assume this should work).

For Visual Studio 2008 the template is stored at

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates
    \CSharp\Code\1033\Interface.zip"
```

This is described in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873411/prevent-visual-studio-from-adding-default-references-and-usings-for-new-classes/894768#894768).

Comment: This works for changing new Interfaces, Classes, and such but not for changing the output from the Refactor tool's "Extract Interface" function. :(   Thanks though.

Comment: @Rox Wen: Ok, I see. Another thing that came to my mind: VS also has a built-in code snippet for creating new interfaces. Maybe this one is used and you can modify that? The location for that one is somewhere under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\interface.snippet".

Comment: @0xA3 No, just tried the snippet. It's not that. Can you think of anywhere else maybe?

Comment: @Heliac: Did the path match your Visual Studio version?

Comment: My path varied slightly (VS2012), but I did the correct thing. Like @RoxWen said... this does not apply to the "Extract Interface" generation tool, only to Add New

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reference, but I have a wild guess as to why it is internal by default.

Let's say you have 3 projects / assemblies: log4net (a 3rd party API), MyApp.Util, and MyApp.Web (a Web project).  Web references Util, which references log4net.  Web does *not* reference log4net, and you want to keep it that way.

Inside of DAL, say you have an internal class, and one of its members references a type defined in log4net.  It could be the return type or one of the parameter types of a method, or the type of a property.

Let's say you extract an interface from the aforementioned class, including the aforementioned member that references log4net.  Well, if you make that member public (part of a public interface) and reference a type that implements it, you then *require* that the Web project reference log4net.

By making the interface internal, Web may continue to be ignorant of log4net.

Comment: @John - I have _basically_ tried this.  I'm looking at an example now where Web references DAL references NHibernate, but Web does not reference (and cannot use) NHibernate.  If Web references, say, a type that implements NHibernate.ISession, then it will no longer build because it requires the NHibernate reference.  I.e., you may break a build somewhere if you make an existing type implement a public interface because all inheritance in C# (in .NET?) is public.

Comment: @John - I marked it CW for more authoritative answers as to the motive, and so others can edit for correctness.  Was that a bad idea?  :(  Note to self: RTM.