# Why does VS2012 "Extract Interface" generate private (sorry, internal) interfaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, interface, private

This is just a minor irritation, but I cannot fathom why they designed it this way. If you "Extract Interface" on a class, it always creates a class without an access modifier, in other words, it is a private interface. Can anyone tell me how you would **ever** use a private interface?

**Edit**

My mistake, I should have said internal... this question seems to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024199/why-are-extracted-interfaces-internal-rather-than-public).

Comment: I too agree it is strange that the interface doesn't at least get the modifier of the original class, or that there is an option for modifier in the wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out in earlier answer access is not private for interfaces but internal.

By default any `Property/Class/Interface` are created without access modifiers. If this is an annoyance for you, you can find detailed description of how to change access modifiers for a class in the Visual Studio's template [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873411/prevent-visual-studio-from-adding-default-references-and-usings-for-new-classes/894768#894768).

You can customize it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that only works if you add a new interface. I don't know if "Extract Interface" has its own unique template somewhere perhaps (?)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because you tried to suggest a (free) workaround at least :-)

Comment: I tried to find custom template for VisualStudio's Refactor -> Extract Interface. Couldnt find much info. Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 4):

It's not private, it's internal when there is no access modifier.

Only some elements such as fields become private if the modifier is missing.

You can very clearly see this behavior when simply creating a new console application: The `Program` class also does not have a modifier, and it is for sure not private ;-).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm asking about :-) I've edited my question... seems to be a duplicate anyway

Answer (score 0):

The default access modifier for interfaces is **internal**. Also, I recommend you to use 'Resharper' as it has lots of refactoring options.