# Class modifier for automatically generated classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

When I add a new class to a project, the class modifier/access specifier for the newly created class in Visual Studio is ommitted, thereby making it `internal`.

Is there a way I can specify in Visual Studio settings that whenever I ask for a new class to be created, please make the class `public`?

I looked in the Tools->Options menu but couldn't find anything. I am guessing it could be in the **Templates** folder in the **My Documents\Visual Studio xxxx** folder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change the file templates (or simply provide secondary file templates), [like so](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/11/05/2556.aspx). However,  before you do that, I would ask myself: does it really take *that* much effort to add the desired accessibility? I tend to err on the side of the pragmatic when it comes to this... if I wanted *significantly* different templates, I might do it. Otherwise... meh.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create your own template to do this, or use code snippets, or perhaps a tool like ReSharper, which has its own snippet mechanism.

However, this is likely to be a bad idea. You will be making things public that do not need to be public. You're better off starting everything as `internal`, and making them public only as required.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search turned up this:

> [Prevent Visual Studio from adding default references and usings for new classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873411/prevent-visual-studio-from-adding-default-references-and-usings-for-new-classes)

The answer demonstrates that you can change the default class template.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you omit the modifier on a class it is either:

- internal (non-nested classes)
- private (on nested classes)

I just thought I'd throw that out there (that it's not *ALWAYS* internal if omitted).

---

But, if you really want to change templates you'll want to generally go to the installation folder (I'll use the default folders):

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE**

In there, you will find the various template folders. You're looking for the following (if you dig deeper): **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip**

Just alter the Class.cs file in there. Oh, and in case you mess it up here's the original version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

You're desired version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The only time something is 'public' without being marked 'public', is `get` and `set` constructs for properties, when the property itself is `public` :)  From Jon Skeet's book :)